# Set automatic firstday

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want to set up automatic value of prameter 'firstday' in the fullcalendar. I have to manualy set number 0-6.

I would like to implement function:

```
  var fday=new Date()
  document.write([fday.getDay()])
```

to

```
firstDay: **HERE**
```

But I don't know how.

I need it for calendar where people may subscribe for a prayer.

Comment: Hi @slavo, welcome to SO. Please, try to be as much specific as possible in your questions. I think your question is not clear. Anyway I've try to answer what I think you are asking. In addition, I would remove that website link: a - Questions and answers should be as much universal as possible . b - It looks like spam

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the firstDay you can do:

```
var yourDate  = // Let's assume here you have your Date Object
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    firstDay: yourDate.getDay()
});
```

If you want to set the firstDay based on the current day:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    firstDay: moment().toDate().getDay()
});
```

Keep in mind you cannot use:

```
moment().startOf('week').isoWeekday()
```

Because

> moment.js Sunday = 7
>   fullCalendar Sunday = 0

Comment: Instead of using Moment, why not just use `new Date().getDay()`?

Comment: Also possible @ScottKaye I wrote it thinking on getting a parameter from fullcalendar, which uses moments.